# Convolution of a matrix and a vector i.e. inputs of different dimensions

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, convolution, code-conversion

That is a follow-up question of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837987/convert-matlabs-conv2-to-python):

I do have Matlab code which I want to convert to Python which includes `conv2`. I can mimic its behavior in Python doing:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

def conv2(x, y, mode='same'):
    return np.rot90(signal.convolve2d(np.rot90(x, 2), np.rot90(y, 2), mode=mode), 2)
```

If I then call

```
f = [[2, 3, 4], [1, 6, 7]]
g = [[9, 1, 0], [2, 5, 8], [1, 3, 3]]

print conv2(f, g)
print conv2(g, f)
```

it gives me the same output as Matlab's

```
conv2([[2,3,4];[1,6,7]], [[9,1,0];[2,5,8];[1,3,3]], 'same')
conv2([[9,1,0];[2,5,8];[1,3,3]], [[2,3,4];[1,6,7]], 'same')
```

However, Matlab's `conv2` also works when one argument is a vector. For example,

```
conv2([[2,3,4];[1,6,7]], [9,1,0]', 'same')
```

gives:

```
   11   57   67
    1    6    7
```

I fail to get this output in Python though, as the standard functions usually require the same input dimensions. For example:

```
signal.convolve(f, [9, 1, 0])
```

yields

> ValueError: in1 and in2 should have the same dimensionality

and

```
signal.convolve2d(f, [9, 1, 0])
```

> ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array

How can I achieve the same output for inputs of different dimensions?

Comment: MATLAB doesn't have 'vectors', at least not in the sense of numpy's 1d arrays.  The minimum dimension in MATLAB is 2d, so it always works with matrices.  That's fundamental difference that you need to keep in mind with comparing MATLAB and numpy code.  But you can easily add a dimension in numpy with `[:,np.newaxis]` or `reshape`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just turn the 1d array into a 2d one.

```
In [71]: f = np.array([[2, 3, 4], [1, 6, 7]])
    ...: g = np.array([[9, 1, 0], [2, 5, 8], [1, 3, 3]])
In [72]: h = np.array([9,1,0])
In [73]: conv2(f,g)
Out[73]: 
array([[ 71, 108,  51],
       [ 26,  71, 104]])
In [74]: conv2(f, h[:,None])
Out[74]: 
array([[11, 57, 67],
       [ 1,  6,  7]])
In [75]: h[:,None]
Out[75]: 
array([[9],
       [1],
       [0]])
```

In Octave your `[9,1,0]'` is a column matrix:

```
>> conv2([[2,3,4];[1,6,7]], [9,1,0]', 'same')
ans =
   11   57   67
    1    6    7

>> [9,1,0]'
ans =
   9
   1
   0
```

In MATLAB everything is 2d (or higher). `numpy` allows 1d arrays.

`np.rot90` applied to `h` is the same as `h[None,:]` or `h` created as a 2d array from `[[9,1,0]]`:

```
In [76]: np.rot90(h[:,None])
Out[76]: array([[9, 1, 0]])
```

In octave/matlab you could skip the transpose by making the column matrix right at the start:

```
conv2([[2,3,4];[1,6,7]], [9;1;0], 'same')
```

The numpy equivalent is:

```
conv2(f,[[9],[1],[0]])
```

Comment: Yes, adding an extra dimension is what I ended up with as well using `np.expand_dims` (see my answer). Thanks for your detailed explanation (upvoted and accepted).

Answer (score 0):

Seems the easiest solution is just to use e.g. [`numpy.expand_dims`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) and then pass a two dimensional input. For the example above it would be:

```
g2 = np.array([9, 1, 0])
g2 = np.expand_dims(g2, 0)
```

Then

```
conv2(f, g2.transpose())
```

gives me

```
array([[11, 57, 67],
       [ 1,  6,  7]])
```

which is identical to the Matlab output.